# How to send custom email template in batch?

Tags: email, batch, template

I work in higher education.  We have a custom object, Application, and a custom email template, to send emails to applicants based on the information in their Applications.  I was given a list of applicants who have their Applications in place.  Is there a way in SF to choose a email template and send emails in batch?

Comment: Are you looking to do this in a apex batch process?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to do this declaratively on a one-off basis in lightning, you can watch the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nWGYZJ79B8) to see how it's done. You can also read the official documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_list_email_create.htm&type=0).

Essentially, all you need to do is select your contacts from the Contacts tab, click add to campaign, and paste your email content or insert it from the template you've already created.